# Using AWSTask, How to declare a block as a variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, objective-c-blocks

I'm using AWS and need help with AWSTask please.  Basically I have some very large blocks that I want to declare as variables for readability.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/awstask.html

for example this bit of code:

```
[task continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    //do something
    return nil;
}];
```

How do I extract the block as a local variable?  This is what I've got so far:

`void (^myBlock)(AWSTask *task) = ^(AWSTask *task){
        //do something
        return nil;
    };
[task continueWithSuccessBlock:myBlock];`

Which gives an error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^__strong)(AWSTask *__strong)' with an expression of type 'void *(^)(AWSTask *__strong)'
```

Here is the method declaration:

```
- (AWSTask *)continueWithSuccessBlock:(AWSContinuationBlock)block;
```

Here is the typedef involved:

```
typedef __nullable id(^AWSContinuationBlock)(AWSTask<ResultType> *task);
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing the return type `void`. Also, you were returning `nil` from  a void block, so I removed that line. Here is the correct syntax:

```
void (^myBlock)(AWSTask *task) = ^void(AWSTask *task){
    //Do something with the AWSTask
};

[task continueWithSuccessBlock:myBlock];
```

In terms of return types, blocks are essentially like methods, in that they must return the type that was declared.

This is a helpful reference: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/,
which is just a mirror to the more explicitly-named domain here: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/

Here are two more decent references from Apple's Docs, although they are not comprehensive:

[A Short Practical Guide to Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html)

[Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Good luck, I hope that helps!

Comment: I get a slightly different error with that approach:  Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^const __strong)(AWSTask *__strong)' to parameter of type 'AWSContinuationBlock _Nonnull' (aka 'id  _Nullable (^)(AWSTask<ResultType> * _Nonnull __strong)')

Comment: @Peter I wonder where the (^const __strong) is coming from. Also, what Xcode are you running?

Comment: XCode 7.3.1 and pod 'AWSCore', '2.4.7'